# What are the exclusion limits on WIMPs?

Tags: experimental-physics, astrophysics, astronomy, dark-matter, wimps

As I understand the way dark matter WIMP exclusion plots work, they are cross-sections (usually 2D) of the fuzzy boundary surface of a hyperdimensional property space, defining a fuzzy volume of that property space, the exterior points of which represent sets of properties of WIMPs that have been excluded (more or less) by experiment.

What are the dimensions of this property space that have been explored by experiment and what are their confidence interval bounds?

If this is too general a question, what are the experimentally established bounds on just the two properties, mass and size, for electrically neutral WIMPs?

Answer (score 0):

A much easier way to think of these exclusion plots is as a very definite line that is ruled out at the stated confidence given a set of well-defined assumptions.

It is necessary to define a set of assumptions when comparing the results from different experiments with each other. Just to make that point, consider an extreme model (which I am making up right now) where only experiment A was sensitive due to a clump of dark matter going through it during its measuring time, whereas all other experiments have missed that clump of dark matter and thus have no sensitivity at all. You probably agree with me that such a clump is unlikely, but there is nothing in the data that would rule it out. So, yes, there is a fuzzy hyperdimensional property space, but its fuzzy boundaries are nowhere well-defined, in particular, they are not nearly Gaussian but have arbitrarily wide tails.

That said, typical assumptions are that (1) WIMPs make up all the dark matter, (2) that their density at the Solar location is 0.3GeV/cm3, (3) that they form an isothermal halo with characteristic velocity (~230km/s) at rest in the Galactic frame, that that distribution is truncated at some Galactic escape speed (~650km/2), (5) that these WIMPs scatter e.g. purely spin-independently, (6) that the target nuclei are well-modeled by some nuclear form factor (e.g. the Helm form factor), and then (7) a bunch of assumptions of how you think your detector works, such as energy thresholds, cut acceptances, etc. We can now go through these assumptions one by one and ask what happens if we vary them "within reason", where you are free to define yourself what you mean by that. For example, (1) and (2) just linearly scale the cross-section limits up and down. (3) and (4) aren't all that important for spin-independent interactions (but Galactic streams can really mess things up, and e.g. the "inelastic dark matter" model amplifies the dependence on this assumption), (5) is now well-taken care of by dedicated experiments (notably LZ/XENON & PICO) and theories (effective field theory treatments), (6) doesn't impact the spin-independent result very much if you replace it by other form factors, e.g. those from Chiral EFT, and (7), well, that's always a lot of fun when collaborations publish their results ;)

For WIMP direct detection, confidence intervals are usually reported at (only) 90% confidence level.

Given these assumptions, the plots you find in the various papers answer your last question, they represent the experimentally established bounds on cross section (aka "size") as function of mass.